# Imported model have Bones that are straight lines

Tags: animation, bones

I imported a Collada file of an Eevee but it's has all of the armature but the bones are just dotted lines unlike the bones that i created can you help me. It's making it hard to animate. i tried changing the preference to sticks and others in the armature setting but it does not do anything.[image]

Comment: I have noted that too, and just now know why that is (because I import from Source very often). Each bone is actually disconnected from each other and are only mm big. Because they are disconnected you can actually stretch/move each limb around. If they were connected the stretching/moving would be very difficult. How to turn those "parent lines" into other shapes I have no idea. Just thought I'd share my knowledge.

Comment: Nope I tried that nothing happened. The dotted lines are still dotted lines. I want to change the dotted lines back into Default Bone figure.

Comment: Like I said, I have no idea how to change the "parent lines"... Actually, those are called "Relationship Lines" into different shapes. If you make a bone chain (armature) and try to move the last one in `Pose mode` you'll notice you cannot move it, only rotate it. If you take an object and Parent it to another object (`CTRL+P`) you will see that same dotted line.

Comment: @PhonePyae Could you upload your blend file and the collada file here blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so I can try to help you?